# When to flag a comment for review?

Tags: discussion

I just ran into a comment that seemed rather personal and angry and was thinking of flagging it but wasn't sure exactly what qualifies as a candidate for flagging.  Took a look at the help page but didn't see anything relevant (although I could have missed it).

The comment is clearly an angry "who the heck do you think you are blah blah blah..." no swear words or racism or anything like that, just someone annoyed at someone else's comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our site gets a **lot** of comments. As such, I take a "guilty until proven innocent" view on them. Here's my algorithm for comment flagging:

- Is this a clarifying question or a response by the OP to a clarifying question that hasn't been edited into the main question?
- Is this a **clear** suggestion for how to improve the question/answer it's posted on?
- Is this a suggestion for how others should behave on the site posted by a mod or a high rep user?

If none of the above, this comment is No Longer Needed. Flag it as NLN and be on your way.

---

<sup>**Note:** This is for comments on the main site. Comments on meta will rarely be removed unless they are *very* off-topic</sup>

Comment: As for the suggestions on how to behave: Even those are no-longer-needed if they've served their purpose, e.g. if I link someone a meta and they've seen it, and it doesn't add much else, they're free to flag the comment as 'no-longer-needed'.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I was thinking more of the "**Comments are for suggestions only...**" kind of comments. I agree if they're directed and served their purpose they should be flagged.

Answer (score 1):

We're pretty strict with comments on this site. Unless it's a request for clarification or a suggestion of improvement it's likely that a comment should be flagged and removed.

If a comment is rude or abusive then it definitely should be flagged and removed.